# Error formulario expresión regular, ¿como se formularia en el if?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function functionName() {
  var parrafo = document.createElement('input');
  var texto = document.createTextNode('');
  parrafo.appendChild(texto);
  enlace=document.getElementById('parrafos').appendChild(parrafo);
}

function validacion() {
  aprobado=document.getElementById("val").value; // nos pasa lo introducido en el impup

  if ( !(/^[A-Z]\d{3}$/.test(aprobado)){
    alert("esta mal.");
  }
  else{
    alert("La clave es correcta.");

  }

}
```

Comment: agrega más detalles de lo que deseas haces. Edita tu pregunta dando clic [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/119802/edit)

Comment: Claro, nunca ejecutas validacion()

Answer (score 0):

Hola porque no intentas crear una variable y asignarle tu expresión regular

```
var expreg = new RegExp("/^[A-Z]\d{3}$/"); 
if ( expreg.test(aprobado)){
alert("esta mal."); }
else{ alert("La clave es correcta.");}
```

Comment: Esto es incorrecto. Al usar el constructor de `RegExp()` no hay que usar delimitadores, y las barras hay que escaparlas. ¿Probaste el código antes de publicarlo? Además, si estuviese bien escrito, no tendría ninguna diferencia con lo publicado con el autor. Esto no responde a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque debes verificar el valor del input cada ves que se escriba, por que osino la asignación se realiza solo una ves, y por esto nunca llegará a verificarlo.

PD: El largo del valor debe ser igual a 4, porque pides una letra y 3 digitos.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
 var e = document.getElementById("pass"),
     regex = /^[A-Z]\d{3}$/, v;
     e.addEventListener("keyup", event => { // Cada ves que se presiono una tecla y luego se soltó ( key - up )
     v = e.value;
     if(v.length === 4 && !regex.test(v)) {
     alert("Error");
     e.style.border = "2px solid red";
     }
     else if (v.length === 4 && regex.test(v)) {
     alert("Todo correcto..");
     e.style.border = "2px solid green";
     }
     });
});
```

```html
Contraseña: <input type="text" id="pass">
```